# How can I create a hasManyThrough relationship using a pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-10

I realize this question has been asked many times throughout SO. What I'm finding is that answers/suggestions are for much older versions of Laravel, or are using raw SQL to create the join(s).

I am trying to understand how I can use a `hasManyThrough` relationship via a pivot table.
[This Medium article](https://darkghosthunter.medium.com/laravel-has-many-through-pivot-elegantly-958dd096db) has been really helpful, but I am not seeing a `->using` method in Laravel 10x.

I have 3 models that I am working with:

- Location
- Resource
- Activity

A location can have many resources & a resource can have many activities.
The resource/activity is a `ManyToMany` relationship, as many resources can share the same activites.

Here is my `Location` model:

```
public function resources(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Resource::class);
}

...

public function activities(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Activity::class, Resource::class);
}
```

Here is my `Resource` model:

```
public function location(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
}

...

public function activities(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Activity::class)->withTimestamps()
        ->using(new class extends Pivot {
            use HasUuids;
    });
}
```

When I `dd` the `location->activities` relationship:

```
dd($location->activities);

// Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column activities.resource_id does not exist
```

Which is correct, that *doesn't* exist. I need something more like:

```
activity_resource.resource_id
```

as the selector.

I've also tried following the docs to do something like this:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
    Activity::class,
    Resource::class,
    'activity_id', // Foreign key on the environments table...
    'resource_id', // Foreign key on the deployments table...
    'location_id', // Local key on the projects table...
    'resource_id' // Local key on the environments table...
);
```

But that doesn't quite get into the pivot table.

I feel that I am really close to what I am looking for, but missing the pivot piece. How can I use eloquent to create the `hasManyThrough` via a pivot table?

Comment: `hasManyThrough` is designed to work like `A hasMany B hasMany C`, where `A hasMany C through B`, but it doesn't work when the relationship between `B` and `C` is a `belongsToMany`. In my experience, I've had to use an external package [`hasManyDeep`](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) that handles the type of relationship you have here.